# How to get embedded object Titile in excel vba?

Tags: vba, excel

how to get embedded object Titile in excel vba

```
enter code here

For Each cboTemp In Worksheets(sheetname).OLEObjects
Debug.Print cboTemp.Index, cboTemp.Name, cboTemp.Application.Caption, 
cboTemp.progID, cboTemp.FileName
```

Here how to get filename or title of the embedded object file(cboTemp.FileName) **error proerty not defined**

or cboTemp.SourceName **not working**

Note:my case excel is the file

Answer (score 0):

There is no FileName property.If the workbook is **embedded**, then you can't get its file name as it doesn't really have one. If it's **linked**, then the `SourceName` property contains the linked file name (and the `ProgID will` give an error).

Comment: what is linked means? how to linked to file?

Comment: When you insert a workbook into a worksheet, you have the option to link to the original file. If you do that, it's linked, not just embedded.